# Scalloping vs Site error in VOR

Tags: vor

I am not able to understand the difference between scalloping and site error in VOR because the theoretical defination of both of them is almost same

Comment: Quote the definitions you’re confused about?

Comment: See at the end of [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29900/3201) for the difference between scalloping and bending errors, and the definitions in ICAO documents (near [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFfxi.png)).

Answer (score 1):

Scalloping error is smooth variation in the path  provided by the VOR(radial in case of vor) within the specified limits.

Site error is the error in VOR signal due to site problem like terrain, alignment error, equipment error etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate regarding scalloping. What does smooth variation in signal means