# What is the VOR reference signal?

Tags: vor

What is the VOR (VHF Omnidirectional Range) reference signal?
I have to calculate the spectrum of this signal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range has a good description

Comment: @mins That's very helpful and complete documentation. The best answer! Thank you for finding time to help me.

Comment: See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27689/3201), the reference is a 30 Hz sine, but depending on the type (CVOR/DVOR), the reference is transmitted either as a AM sideband (DVOR) or as a FM subcarrier at 9.96 kHz (480 Hz swing) sent as DSB-SC (CVOR). The other signal is the variable, also a 30 Hz sine. The corresponding spectrum is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUwE7.png) (missing the id tone and voice channel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VOR Ground Station is aligned with magnetic North. It emits two signals:

- a 360° sweeping variable signal
- an omni-directional reference signal

When an aircraft receives those signals, its receiver compares those and a measures the phase difference. This gives a precise radial position of the aircraft which is displayed on its Omni-Bearing Indicator (OBI), Horizontal Situation Indicator (HSI) or a Radio Magnetic Indicator (RMI), or a combination of two different kinds.

[This picture shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range#Operation) the two signals:

[image]

- Blue is 360° sweeping signal
- Green is omni-directional reference signal

Comment: This is very enlightening! And also I would like to know more about this omni-directional reference signal (blue one). For example if it is sinusoidal, and all other informations for calculating its spectrum. Thank you!

Comment: Trying to fig out why they made the reference signal flash in that gif. I guess that's indicating when it's at 0° phase?

Comment: @TomMcW: Yes it's misleading, it looks like the bearing is determined by timing the interval between a north pulse and the maximum strength of a supposed thin beam (and I saw another post on the site where it's interpreted this wrong way).