# Is it possible for a civilian to use a VORTAC station?

Tags: navigation, ifr-navigation, radio-navigation

Suppose you have a [Cessna 208 Grand Caravan Amphibian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_208_Caravan) and you want to use [VORTAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VORTAC) stations on military bases (or somewhere else). Is it possible? Is it legal?

Comment: It's legal.  Tuning a VOR signal is different to area based restrictions. If the wanted the signal restricted, they would encrypt it like some GPS signals.

Comment: @RodneyHawkins I don’t think it is possible to encrypt a VOR signal, which is what you are tuning to when tracking a VORTAC. If they wanted to restrict civilian use they would put in a TACAN and leave off the VOR.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Totally legal to tune it up & use it. If it is a VORTAC, it will work just like every other VORTAC out there. If it is a TACAN, you may be able to get DME from it, but you won”t get bearing from it without a TACAN receiver.

Many, perhaps most VOR’s out there are in fact VORTAC’s — the TACAN station is colocated with the VOR. It is possible to have a VOR-DME station, which gives a civillian user everything a VORTAC does, but no bearing info to TACAN-only military aircraft. And you can have a VOR station with no associated DME at all.

But you won’t find any rule prohibiting you from tuning up any of the above - doesn’t exist (at least in the U.S., nor anywhere else I’ve ever heard of). If the military wanted a NAVAID they could use that you couldn’t, they could put up a TACAN using a channel that civillian DME receivers can’t pair with (ex ch 16X “pairs” to 135.9 - not a frequency in the range civil VOR receivers can tune to) and not publish it. But realistically, they’d probably just use a GPS coordinate & call it good.

(Edit: as @UnrecognizedFallingObject mentioned, it is not the “Y” TACAN channels that conventional VOR receivers can’t pair with, but there are some channels you can’t get DME from using normal VOR tuning — see [this chart](http://www.e-haf.org/PublicFTP/320/UPLOAD_FOLDER/Charts/VOR%20Frequencies%20to%20TACAN%20Channel%20list.pdf).)

Flying ***over*** that navaid on a military base may entail issues with the airspace involved, but that is its own issue, unrelated to using or not using the navaid.

Comment: BTW: it seems that most DME receivers *can* use Y-channels (you'll see plenty of civil DMEs published as "Chan 54(Y)" or whatever, see the I-SAJ DME used with the ILS for KORD RWY 09L for ex.)

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - Good catch! Looks like the X channels pair up to frequencies like 112.3***0***, while the Y channels pair up with .05 higher, so 112.3***5***. Edited post above to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely.  A VORTAC is nothing more than a VOR colocated with a TACAN.  Most VOR-DMEs in the US are VORTACs.  If there happens to be one located on a base you are certainly still able to use it.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: A VORTAC station combines a VOR-DME and a TACAN. It is the result of a cooperation between civil and military worlds to share the same DME (and the navaid place).

- Civil aircraft use includes accessing the VOR part (civil), the DME part (civil and military), but not the TACAN bearing transponder, said otherwise they access the VOR-DME equivalent, or for what civilians are concerned, a VORTAC is a VOR-DME.
- They are not equipped for receiving the TACAN bearing equipment, though nothing prevent them to be equipped with the related UHF receiver.

---

**More details**: A VORTAC station is composed of three signal generators:

- A VOR (VHF) signal used for civil bearing determination.
- A DME (UHF) signal used for range determination
- An UHF signal used for military bearing determination, in theory 9 times more accurate than a VOR.

DME and UHF bearing station components are interrogated by the aircraft, contrary to the VOR which broadcasts continuously.

When civilians use a VORTAC, they actually use the two first signals (VOR-DME). Military use the two last signals (TACAN) and the VOR as a backup if they are equipped, which is normally the case.

Pure TACAN have only the UHF bearing determination signal and the DME signal.

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://www.dbsant.com/)</sup>

Their little size, compared to a [VOR-DME](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/VOR_DME_BUB.JPG), allow them to be used on ships. More: Wikipedia article on [TACAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_air_navigation_system), and [How does Tactical Air Navigation work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27689/how-does-tactical-air-navigation-work)