# Is it legal to install a TACAN receiver on a civilian aircraft?

Tags: avionics, radio-navigation

It is legal to use the DME from a VORTAC station (see [Is it possible for a civilian to use a VORTAC station?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46909/is-it-possible-for-a-civilian-to-use-a-vortac-station/46929#46929) for details), but **is it also legal to use the TACAN for bearing determination?**

This would probably require different equipment, which is not typically installed on a civilian aircraft (see [Why doesn't civil navigation equipment support TACAN?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47871/why-doesnt-civil-navigation-equipment-support-tacan/47941#47941) for details). But the answers to that question do not mention whether or not it is legal to install and use this equipment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy and legally use [TACAN equipment for GA aircraft from Bendix/King](https://www.airteam.eu/tacan), but the system is expensive (close to US\$100,000), relatively heavy and requires rack-mounting.

Comment: They really went all-out in their sales copywriting: "An antenna is a part of this system, to maximilize the range of this system. Thanks to TACAN you will be able to control the pitch angle, and many other."

Comment: What's really funny is that the size and weight of the thing hasn't changed much since I worked on CH-46's in the Marine Corps.

Comment: Isn't € 1 373,96 in American format €1373.96, so we'll under $2000?